# Are 仲がいい and 親しい interchangeable in this context?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I'm trying to construct the sentence, "You two seem pretty close." and I'm curious if the sentences, 二人はかなり仲が良さそうだ。 or 二人はかなり親しそうだ。would work and if there are any differences between the two. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

親しい is relatively bookish. In informal conversations, people usually prefer "(～ちゃんと～ちゃんは)仲がいいね". In formal or written sentences, 親しい and 仲がいい are both common and used interchangeably.